# Test cases failing due to custom modifier

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I am new to solidity and trying to code it on my own before using open Zepplin plugins.

Here is the contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
   
   pragma solidity ^0.8.5;

   contract LeagueWinners {

struct Winner {
    bool exists;
    bool claimed;
    uint256 reward;
}

mapping(address=>Winner) public winners;
mapping (address => bool) private AuthAccounts;


modifier onlyAuthAccounts() {
    require(AuthAccounts[msg.sender], "Auth: caller is not the authorized");
    _;
}

constructor () {
    AuthAccounts[_addr_1] = true;
    AuthAccounts[_addr_2] = true;
}


function addWinner(address _address, uint256 _amount ) public {
       Winner storage winner = winners[_address];
       winner.exists = true;
       winner.reward = _amount;
   }

}
```

I know we have the Ownable plugin from openzepplin. but just trying with my own modifier as I want 2 users to add winners.

The contract works well. but I am facing issues in writing test cases.

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const hre = require("hardhat");

describe("LeagueWinners", function () {
  
  before(async () => {
    LeagueWinners = await ethers.getContractFactory("LeagueWinners");
    leagueWiners = await LeagueWinners.deploy();
    await leagueWiners.deployed();
    [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
  });

  it("Claim Tokens to be deployed and verify owner", async function () {
    expect(await leagueWiners.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
  });

  it("Add Winner", async function () {
    winner = await leagueWiners
      .connect(owner)
      .addWinner(
        "_addr",
        "50000000000000000000"
      );
  });
});
```

Add winner is getting failed, not sure how to pass the AuthAccounts. Any guidance will be great help

Error

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Auth: caller is not the authorized'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass any addresses to the constructor here:

```
constructor () {
    AuthAccounts[_addr_1] = true;
    AuthAccounts[_addr_2] = true;
}
```

You need to add the _addr_1 and _addr_2 into the constructor like this:

```
constructor (address _addr_1, address _addr_2) {
        AuthAccounts[_addr_1] = true;
        AuthAccounts[_addr_2] = true;
    }
```

The compiler shouldn't let you compile this contract so I'm not sure how it lets you deploy it.

Then in your test you need to pass the arguments like this:

```
before(async () => {
    LeagueWinners = await ethers.getContractFactory("LeagueWinners");
    leagueWiners = await LeagueWinners.deploy(addr1, addr2); // HERE
    await leagueWiners.deployed();
    [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
  });
```

Comment: I have hardcoded the address. I don't want to pass arguments.
Let's say I have 2 constant addresses.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a few days, made a solution in this way.

```
constructor () {
    AuthAccounts[msg.sender] = true;
    AuthAccounts[_addr_1] = true;
    AuthAccounts[_addr_2] = true;
}
```

As i was hardcoding other addresses, it was not possible to get signer info in the test cases. Passing **msg.sender** in AuthAccounts helped to achieve that and test cases got passed.

Let me know if there are any other work arounds.